# How to pass ckeditor settings to wysiwyg module?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using WYSIWYG module with CKeditor and custom module that enables image2 widget. Image2 widget are inserting images with height and width attributes in img tag. I need remove these attributes.
Ckeditor have feature called `disallowedConcent` ([doc here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content)) but I don't know out how to apply these setting to my custom modules. Solution is this snippet:

`config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'img[width,height]';`

But I don't know how to passed this to `hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter` function.